# How to stop Magento cron

Tags: php, magento, cron

There are some crons job that have heavy sql queries. But Sometimes because of some another heavy sql is running from somewhere in the Magento at the same time, My cron job takes too much time to execute and slows down the server.

I want to stop my cron job programmatically if it is taking more then some threshold time, so I decided to delete cron job entry from cron_schedule table if it is in running state from more then threshold time. But I think it does not kill the process.

Is there a way to kill cron job from server? If I had process ID then I could fire unix command to kill process but since these cron jobs are handled by cron.php I can not go with this aproach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If your script is heavy then you must fix the script first, it is always bad to think the way around it to solve it. Fixing the script is HIGHLY Recommended**.

Still if you want to stop the cron job programmatically then you can get the process id of CRON job when it start executing at very beginning of the script by [getmypid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php) and then save it in database with date and time. Then you have to make a cron job that should run after your threshold time, which will check if your script is still running then you kill the process by [posix_kill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-kill.php)

Comment: That is good sugggestion. I am checking if it possible for me to get process id for Magento cron jobs